# Save Request url in Curl output

Tags: text-processing, curl

The command below cats a file full of urls and feeds it into gnu parallel. I would like the output in curlresponse.txt to have also the original request url. How can it be done?

```
cat urls.txt  | parallel -j 5  curl -IL -k {} > curlresponse.txt
```

so sample of final output (after all redirects if any) is like this :

```
OriginalUrl
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2019 07:35:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 188
Connection: keep-alive
```

Sometimes the url might be redirected so the final http response should be the one having the original request url.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly:

```
cat urls.txt  |
  parallel -j 5 echo {}';'curl -IL -k {} '|' perl -ne '/^HTTP.* 200/ .. 0 and print' > curlresponse.txt
```

But for situations like this I usually prefer `--tag` which will prepend every line with the input:

```
cat urls.txt  |
  parallel -j 5 --tag curl -IL -k {} '|' perl -ne '/^HTTP.* 200/ .. 0 and print' > curlresponse.txt
```

It often makes further processing easier.